# Not entering while loop in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop

I was trying to implement page rank in hadoop. I created a shell script to iteratively run map-reduce. But the while loop just doesn't work.  I have 2 map-reduce, one to find the initial page rank and to print the adjacency list. The other one will take the output of the first reducer and take that as input to the second mapper.

The shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
CONVERGE=1
ITER=1
rm W.txt W1.txt log*
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
hdfs dfs -rm -r /task-* 

$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.3.3.jar \-mapper "'$PWD/mapper.py'" \-reducer "'$PWD/reducer.py' '$PWD/W.txt'"  \-input /assignment2/task2/web-Google.txt \-output /task-1-output
echo "HERE $CONVERGE"
while [ "$CONVERGE" -ne 0 ]
do
    
    echo "############################# ITERATION $ITER #############################"
    $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.3.3.jar \-mapper "'$PWD/mapper2.py' '$PWD/W.txt' '$PWD/page_embeddings.json'" \-reducer "'$PWD/reducer2.py'" \-input task-1-output/part-00000 \-output /task-2-output
    touch w1
    hadoop dfs -cat /task-2-output/part-00000 > "$PWD/w1"
    CONVERGE=$(python3 $PWD/check_conv.py $ITER>&1)
    ITER=$((ITER+1))
    hdfs dfs -rm -r /task-2-output/x
    echo $CONVERGE
done
```

The first mapper runs perfectly fine and I am getting output for it. The condition for while loop [ '$CONVERGE' -ne 0 ] just gives false so it doesn't enter the while loop to run 2nd map-reduce. I removed the quotes on $CONVERGE and tried it still doesn't work.
I defined CONVERGE at the beginning of the file and is updated in while loop with the output of check.py. The while loop just doesn't run.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Mapreduce already supports running multiple Job classes in one application. If your while loop is a problem, then create a [mcve] since that's not related to hadoop

Comment: Unrelated, but `\-input` and `-input` are the exact same argument; it's the tool, not the shell, that decides if an argument is an option or not.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you are experiencing, but note that the quoting used in your code snippet is different from that in your text: `"$CONVERGE"` is very different from `'$CONVERGE'`, only the first expands the variable. This works as expected: `CONVERGE=1; while [ "$CONVERGE" -ne 0 ]; do echo "CONVERGE=$CONVERGE"; CONVERGE=0; done`.

Answer (score 1):

Self Answer:
I tried doing everything possible to correct the mistakes. But later I was told to download dos2unix and run it again. Surprisingly it worked. The file was being read properly. I don't know why that happened.

Comment: If anyone understands why it didn't work initially and when I installed dos2unix it worked. Then, please comment about it.

Comment: Did you just download `dos2unix`, or did you also run it on your script (or some other file(s))? If running it on files fixed the problem, then the problem was that you had files in DOS/Windows format, rather than unix format. Also, when it wasn't working, did you get any error messages?